# How to add internal testers with iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

iTunes Connect and Test Flight have changed yet again!
Does anyone know how to add internal testers?

When I try to add testers I can only select existing testers - but how do I invite new testers that are NOT in this list?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can add new internal testers to the list in the Users and Roles section of iTunes Connect.

[image: Users & Roles]
[image: Create new user]
[image: Add info]
[image: Set permissions]

Note that to be eligible for internal testing, they'll have to be in the Admin, Legal, or Technical role. Once you add them in this section, they'll be available for selection in the list of testers in TestFlight.

Comment: Role names are changed on iTunesConnect. What roles users are required to have to be internal tester now?

Comment: if is "Developer" group , and apple doc says , if you want a person to be an internal tester and does not know what group to assign him , Go with "App manager"

Answer (score 2):

I believe the current answer is out of date. Internal testers are now added under App Store Connect Users in the Testers & Groups section of Test Flight.
See the description in the screen shot.

[image: Screenshot of iTunes Connect Test Flight panel]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not outdated still if you need to add internal testers, they will appear under App Store Connect Users if you have add them already from "User and Roles" section, only change is that you are now not limited to the Admin, Legal, or Technical role to make them eligible for testing. All roles are valid for testing.

[image: Check this]

Answer (score 2):

Current list of roles for internal testers is: Account Holder, Admin, App Manager, Developer, or Marketing role

Source: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/